# Where can I watch Mushiking anime?

Tags: mushiking

I would like to know more about the anime called *Mushiking*. It is a 52-episode anime (according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mushiking)) which I just can't find.

There are 1-2 segments on YouTube in Japanese, but that is the most that I could find.

Does anyone know what happened to this anime? Or where could I watch it?

Comment: not finding it on youtube wouldn't be too surprising since technically it is illegal to upload anime to youtube. according to [Anime News Network](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=4834) there's no english information so quite possible that your looking for fan subs but they have the link to TV Tokyo's official site so you may get some info there

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you're looking for? Nothing "happened" to it _per se_; it looks like it was just not very popular, seeing as it was basically just a marketing vehicle for a line of games. If you _really_ want to watch it, it looks like you can [buy the DVDs on Amazon Japan](http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B0009OAW0A).

Answer (score 4):

Mushiking was pretty much a large advertisement for a game and didn't get a great following - That isn't to say that anime based on games can't be popular (see Pokémon & Yugioh) , but more often than not efforts to make a company's new product the new "thing" end in failure.

It didn't disappear, rather it faded away in time. A thing that happens to all media, unless it is significantly loved by consumers.

That being said, you can still find the DVDs in some places (Japanese):

[Wow HD](http://www.ie.wowhd.com/DVD/mushiking-the-king-of-beetless-super-battle-movie/dp/22451531)

[Amazon Japan](http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B0009OAW0A) (Thanks @senshin)